# UserPassesTestMixin test function with many to many relation doesn work

Tags: django, many-to-many

Im making website with shopping lists. One of the features will be possibilities of share your list to someone. The problem is I cant figure out how to make test_func in UserPassesTestMixin work with it.

views:

```
class ListDetailUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
   model = ShoppingItem
   template_name = 'xlist_app/ListDetailUpdateView.html'
   context_object_name = 'products'
   fields = ['name', 'count'] 
 ...
   def test_func(self):
       shop_list_id= self.request.resolver_match.kwargs['pk']
       shop_list = ShoppingList.objects.get(id=shop_list_id)
       if self.request.user == shop_list.owner     or      self.request.user == shop_list.owners:
           return True
       return False
```

models:

```
class ShoppingList(models.Model):
   list_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
           related_name='shopping_lists', 
   null = True, blank=True)
   owners = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

As you can see, I have field 'owner' that store who created this list and 'owners' that stores users
to whom the list is shared. I need help with this part:

```
self.request.user == shop_list.owners
```

How to make it work or why it doesnt work?
(When i share list from other account to myself the "403 Forbidden" pops out)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just needed to use 'for' like this:

```
    def test_func(self):
    shop_list_id= self.request.resolver_match.kwargs['pk']
    shop_list = ShoppingList.objects.get(id=shop_list_id)
    #Solution:
    for own in shop_list.owners.all():
        if own == self.request.user:
            return True
    if self.request.user == shop_list.owner:
        return True
    return False
```